# MySQL connection doesn't exist | PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote some code, and I'm calling(require function) .php file which will connect to MySQL base. That file(not file for MySQL connection) I call into other because I want open one connection one time, and close it one time. Error says

> Undefined variable: _hsync_konekcija in C:\Program Files\WAMP\www\hsync_hsync_scripts_hsync_pristup.php on line 21

_hsync_pristup.php file

```
<?php

require('_hsync_scripts/_hsync_baza.php');

function _hsync_pristup()
{
    session_start();

    if(isset($_COOKIE['_hsync_prijavljen'])) $_hsync_id = $_COOKIE['_hsync_prijavljen']; // PRIJAVLJEN
    else if(isset($_SESSION['_hsync_sess_prijavljen'])) $_hsync_id = $_SESSION['_hsync_sess_prijavljen']; // PRIJAVLJEN
    else
    {
        $_hsync_pristup_info = array(
            '_hsync_pristup' => 0
        );

        $_hsync_konekcija->close();
        return ($_hsync_pristup_info);
    }

    /* THIS LINE */ $_hsync_statment = $_hsync_konekcija->prepare("SELECT Zakljucan, Ime, Skin FROM $_hsync_usr WHERE ID = ?"); // LINE 21
    $_hsync_statment->bind_param("i", $_hsync_id);
    $_hsync_statment->execute();
    $_hsync_rezultat = $_hsync_statment->get_result();

    if($_hsync_rezultat->num_rows == 0) // OBIRSAN RAČUN
    {
        $_hsync_pristup_info = array(
            '_hsync_pristup' => -1
        );

        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        setcookie("_hsync_prijavljen", null, -1, "/");

        $_hsync_statment->close();
        $_hsync_rezultat->close();
        $_hsync_konekcija->close();
        return ($_hsync_pristup_info);
    }

    $_hsync_podatci = $_hsync_rezultat->fetch_assoc();
    if($_hsync_podatci["Zakljucan"] != 0) // ZAKLJUČAN RAČUN
    {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        setcookie("_hsync_zakljucan", $_hsync_id, time() + 8, "/");
        setcookie("_hsync_zakljucan_zap", rand(6, 16), time() + 8, "/");
        setcookie("_hsync_prijavljen", null, -1, "/");

        $_hsync_pristup_info = array(
            '_hsync_pristup' => -2
        );

        $_hsync_statment->close();
        $_hsync_rezultat->close();
        $_hsync_konekcija->close();
        return ($_hsync_pristup_info);
    }
    else
    {
        $_hsync_ime = $_hsync_podatci['Ime'];
        $_hsync_skin = $_hsync_podatci['Skin'];
    }

    $_hsync_statment = $_hsync_konekcija->prepare("SELECT ServerID FROM $_hsync_srv_online WHERE ID = ?");
    $_hsync_statment->bind_param("i", $_hsync_id);
    $_hsync_statment->execute();
    $_hsync_rezultat = $_hsync_statment->get_result();

    if($_hsync_rezultat->num_rows != 0) // PRIJAVLJEN NA GAME SERVERU
    {
        $_hsync_podatci = $_hsync_rezultat->fetch_assoc();
        $_hsync_serverid = $_hsync_podatci["ServerID"];

        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        setcookie("_hsync_prijavljen", null, -1, "/");
        setcookie("_hsync_online", $_hsync_id, time() + 8, "/");
        setcookie("_hsync_online_id", $_hsync_serverid, time() + 8, "/");

        $_hsync_pristup_info = array(
            '_hsync_pristup' => -3
        );

        $_hsync_statment->close();
        $_hsync_rezultat->close();
        $_hsync_konekcija->close();
        return ($_hsync_pristup_info);
    }

    if(isset($_COOKIE['_hsync_zabrana'])) return (-4); // IMA ZABRANU PRISTUPA
    else // NEMA ZABRANU
    {
        $_hsync_statment = $_hsync_konekcija->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $_hsync_srv_bnds WHERE ID = ? AND Aktivno = 1"); // TRAŽI DALI JE IMA
        $_hsync_statment->bind_param("i", $_hsync_id);
        $_hsync_statment->execute();
        $_hsync_rezultat = $_hsync_statment->get_result();

        if($_hsync_rezultat->num_rows > 0) // IMA ZABRANU
        {
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
            setcookie("_hsync_prijavljen", null, -1, "/");
            setcookie("_hsync_zabrana", $_hsync_id, time() + 31536000, "/");

            $_hsync_pristup_info = array(
                '_hsync_pristup' => -4
            );

            $_hsync_statment->close();
            $_hsync_rezultat->close();
            $_hsync_konekcija->close();
            return ($_hsync_pristup_info);
        }
    }

    $_hsync_datum = date("d. m. Y.");
    $_hsync_vrijeme = date("H:i:s");

    $_hsync_statment = $_hsync_konekcija->prepare("UPDATE $_hsync_usr SET DatumhSync = ?, VrijemehSync = ? WHERE ID = ?");
    $_hsync_statment->bind_param("ssi", $_hsync_datum, $_hsync_vrijeme, $_hsync_id);
    $_hsync_statment->execute();

    $_hsync_pristup_info = array(
        '_hsync_pristup' => 1,
        '_hsync_ime' => $_hsync_ime,
        '_hsync_id' => $_hsync_id,
        '_hsync_skin' => $_hsync_skin
    );

    return ($_hsync_pristup_info);
}
```

?>

Other file

```
require('_hsync_scripts/_hsync_pristup.php'); // FRIST LINE ON THE TOP OF FILE
```

I don't Know why PHP says that connection variable doesn't exist. `require('_hsync_scripts/_hsync_baza.php');` is on the top, so it's global, right?

Comment: Show us your other file.

Comment: It's a variable scope issue. If you want to use `$_hsync_konekcija` inside your function, you need to declare it inside the function, pass it in as a parameter, or declare it as a global function. You have to explicitly declare global variables inside a function to be able to use them - simply having it at the top of the file doesn't affect anything

Comment: @AndrewCheong Other file is index.php. Function `_hsync_pristup()` checks if is user logged in. I'm newbie in PHP, but I think that other file won't help, because error is in _hsync_pristup.php

Comment: Looks like "$_hsync_konekcija->close();" is called but a connect was never called. (Line 18)

Comment: @Andrewsi In PAWN if I define variable on the top, I can use it in all functions. PAWN and PHP are like brothers, right? Why here this way doesn't work like in PAWN?

Comment: @SilvioCro - you'll have to ask the designers of PHP and PAWN. This is how global variables work in PHP.

Comment: @Andrewsi Should I only call(with require) file with all functions and variables? Maybe that will solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If _hsync_konekcija is global, then tell the function that!  Prior to accessing it in the function, put

```
global $_hsync_konekcija;
```

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php for a fuller description of variable scope.

Comment: `global $_hsync_konekcija = new mysqli(...);`
PHP says

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';' `

Comment: @SilvioCro That's not what the answer says.

Comment: @JonStirling Then I didn't understand You. How I'll connect to base then?

Comment: @SilvioCro Re-read the answer, read the documentation that was linked to. All the information is there.

Comment: @JonStirling I use object-oriented PHP. Any way I tried did nothing. Still same error and problem.

Comment: I did it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a scoping issue. Basically your function cant access local variables (the one you include from the file) that are instantiated outside of it.

Two options really.

1) Require the '_hsync_baza.php' file within your function.

```
<?php
function _hsync_pristup(){
    session_start();
    require('_hsync_scripts/_hsync_baza.php');
    ...
}
```

2) 'use' the variables you need.

```
<?php
require('_hsync_scripts/_hsync_baza.php');

function _hsync_pristup() use ($_hsync_konekcija, $_hsync_SOMETHING_ELSE, ..){
   ...
}
```

As a final recomendation i would remove the session_start() call from within your function to the top of the file. $_SESSION variables are 'SUPER GLOBALS' so despite being initialised from outside of the function they can be accessed from within it.

Hope this helps

Comment: I like frist option, but then I'll need to connect more than one time to base.
Frist cunnection will be in `_hsync_pristup()` and second will be later in `index.php`. Why connect two times when you can connect one time?
Also I tried with this in index.php `require('_hsync_scripts/_hsync_baza.php'); require('_hsync_scripts/_hsync_pristup.php');`
Include frist base, then file with function. I tought that will work.